# Should I make a new layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, optimization, view

After the user gets to a certain score, I wan't to display a medal next to the users name. Doing this pro grammatically will make the image disappear after the user leaves the app. How can I accomplish a permanent `medal` on the layout after an event. Will I have to create two layouts, one with the medal and one without, and use `setContentView` in an `if-statement` in the `onCreate();`?

```
if (userHasMedal){

setContentView(R.layout.medal)
}else{
setContentView(R.layout.noMedal)
}
```

**Is that the only way I can do it?** It seems silly to create a whole other layout just to display one more picture...

I'm sure there is an easy way of doing this, but I am unaware of what to do besides for possibly create two layouts.

Thanks for your help,

Ruchir

Comment: How are you currently saving the user's score? If they leave the app do they have to restart?

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan Shared Preferences.

Comment: So save the score to shared preferences and when you go back to the application if the user's score is over the medal threshold display the image. No need for another layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always have your `medal` icon in layout and set its visibility to `GONE` or `VISIBLE` depending on the condition. Of course, once user leaves the app (or the activity goes to background) you want to keep/save/persist the score somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you can handle the adding of the medal during `onResume()`. As for why onResume, we want it to check and display whenever the Activity goes active.

```
onResume()
{
//getting/verifying points
//Handle medal adding (Check if image exists, add/modify if needed)
}
```

The most important thing is that you need some way to save this score and access it in particular. This was not addressed in your question so this is the best I can do.